# Xlsxwriter Excel Chart Custom Data Label Position

Tags: python, xlsxwriter

I am drawing an excel scatter chart with python and xlsx writer and use custom data labels for one series. But I can not set the position of the custom labels like I can with the default labels. If I set the position of the custom labels they dont change in the chart. In the debugger or if I check their label options in excel itself I can see the changed position values, but they are not applied in the drawing.
At default the custom labels seem to bet set at right. I want them on top but I cant get this. The code is like that:

```
chart.add_series(  .., 'data_labels': {'custom': my_custom_labels, 'position': 'above'})
```

But the changes wont appy to the chart.
I also found i can set the default label position (label_position_default) in the chart object (which is right on default) but it wont change the custom label position either.
Anyone has an idea how to get a custom data label on top position?

Comment: Positioning of custom labels in XlsxWriter isn't currently supported. At least, custom positioning isn't supported. If custom labels don't take on the positioning of the rest of the series then that may be a bug. In which case you should open a defect in GitHub with a small, complete, working example that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: I just checked it and it is a bug. No need to raise a defect. I'll do it myself.

Comment: GitHub issue for reference: https://github.com/jmcnamara/XlsxWriter/issues/754

Comment: Fix on the main branch.

Answer (score 1):

You can acheive that using: 'position': 'outside_end'

```
chart.add_series(  .., 'data_labels': {'custom': my_custom_labels, 'position': 'outside_end'})
```